# MATLAB: Generating and Visualizing Mother Wavelet of different scale

Tags: matlab, wavelet

In MATLAB, there is a function `wavefun` that outputs both the scaling and wavelet functions. To generate a Daubechies, the following command can be used:

```
[phi,psi,xval] = wavefun('db40',10);
```

The question I have is: How to generate a Daubechies at different scales and visualizing them? For instance, generating a similar Daubechies with frequency twice larger.

Answer (score 1):

[Subsequent wavelets, spanning a specific range of scales are generated by shifting and scaling the Mother Wavelet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Continuous_wavelet_transforms_.28continuous_shift_and_scale_parameters.29)

Therefore, to produce *"...a similar Daubechies with frequency twice larger..."* you would have to "take every other sample" of the Mother Wavelet. For more information, please see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) and the [Wavelet Toolbox User Guide](http://feihu.eng.ua.edu/NSF_TUES/w7_1a.pdf) on the section about the discrete wavelet transform.

It may also be useful to have a quick look at [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)) and [upsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling) concepts in DSP.

Hope this helps.